# Received [object Object] in strongloop API

Tags: node.js, strongloop

In my remodeMethod, I set the incoming data as string like below:

```
{
    http: {path: '/_html', verb: 'post'},
    accepts: [
        {arg: 'html', type: 'string', http: {source: 'body'}, description: 'HTML code.', required: true }
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'data', type: 'object'}
}
```

And my request header is 'content-type': 'text/plain', my request body is plain text.

I put console.log( html ) at the first line when my function caught the variable.
It displays [object Object].

But I expect pure text. What can I do?
I tried JSON.stringify( html ) but it returns "[object Object]".

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(html,null,2));` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(html),null,2));`

Comment: also, you have explicitly requested the return format to be `object` with this line: `returns: {arg: 'data', type: 'object'}`. So you should expect an object with a key called `data`.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(html,null,2)); 
returned 
"[object Object]"

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(html),null,2));   returned    SyntaxError: Unexpected token o\n    at Object.parse (native)\n

Comment: You can actually go to the **Network** panel of the Chrome developer tools to see the actual response in plain text (refresh the page and find that request).

Comment: Raw response is: {"data":{"result":"[object Object]","time_used":{"trending":0.001}}}